# Where can I find release notes for Microsoft.AspNet.OData

Tags: odatalib

We are upgrading our Microsoft.AspNet.OData from 6.0.0 to latest stable version. 
I am looking for release notes to know any breaking changes but I couldn't find any page detailing so. Not even on https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData

Where can I find release notes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the notes for each release at: http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#14-06-webapi-7-1-0

Comment: Would please answer this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65551331/using-odatarouteprefix-and-odataroute-for-odata-attributerouting-is-not-working