# ASP.NET Core OData v8.0 Routing Endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

#### Objective

To invoke OData Controllers with Endpoints defined differently to the controller name convention.

#### Reason

Worried about the brittleness of exposing internal controller names as paths...limiting the ability to rename controllers later.

#### Context

Using the latest OData libraries available currently (ASP.NET Core OData 8.0 RC)

Trying to make sense of a lot of documentation on MSDN that appears to be legacy/no longer applicable. Working with the what I think is the latest info available, here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/g

- Legacy/Sunset/removed:

  - `ODataRoutePrefixAttribute` are legacy .
  - `ODataRouteAttribute` are legacy at this point.
- Current approach:

  - `RouteAttribute` + Verb based Endpoint routing in ASP.NET Core.

So, I'd like to use be able to query `api/odata/anyotherroutename/get(1)` rather than `api/odata/someinternalnameforthecontroller/get(1)`

```cs
[Route("AnyOtherRouteName")]
public class PresentationLayerExampleAEntityOData03Controller :
             ModuleQueryableODataControllerBase<ExampleAEntityDto>{
  ...
}
```

#### Registration

When building the edm model definition, the ControllerName used was developed from a helper method that rips off the `Controller` suffix from the controller class type name -- and if there is a `RouteAttribute` it reads its value (replacing `[Controller]` with the above value).
In this case the controller is being registered under `AnyOtherRouteName`.

#### Results

Unfortunately...
`https://localhost:44406/$odata` shows it -- but listing it under **Non**-OData Endpoint mappings rather than OData endpoints:

```cs
App.Modules.DevLearn.Presentation.Web.Api.OData.Controllers.Instances.Demo.PresentationLayerExampleAEntityOData03Controller.Get (App.Modules.DevLearn.Presentation.Web) GET AnyOtherRouteName
App.Modules.DevLearn.Presentation.Web.Api.OData.Controllers.Instances.Demo.PresentationLayerExampleAEntityOData03Controller.Get (App.Modules.DevLearn.Presentation.Web) GET AnyOtherRouteName/Get
```

rather than something more akin to:

```cs
App.Modules.DevLearn.Presentation.Web.Api.OData.Controllers.Instances.Demo.PresentationLayerExampleAEntityOData02Controller.Get (App.Modules.DevLearn.Presentation.Web) GET api/odata/v{version}/PresentationLayerExampleAEntityOData02 Yes
App.Modules.DevLearn.Presentation.Web.Api.OData.Controllers.Instances.Demo.PresentationLayerExampleAEntityOData02Controller.Get (App.Modules.DevLearn.Presentation.Web) GET api/odata/v{version}/PresentationLayerExampleAEntityOData02/$count  Yes
```

#### Other Outcomes

I tried several combinations in utter despair...and the results are not much better. I'm not getting any form of combination going on.

```
Where Prefix = "api/odata/v{version}/":

Route ("Things") + HttpVerb("") = FAIL to register as an odata route.
Route ("Things/") + HttpVerb("") = FAIL to register as an odata route.
Route ("Things") + HttpVerb("Things/") = FAIL to register as an odata route.
Route ("api/odata/v{version}/Things") + HttpVerb ("") = FAIL to register as an odata route.
Route ("api/odata/v{version}") + HttpVerb ("Things/") = FAIL to register as an odata route.

ERROR - Route ("") + HttpVerb ("api/odata/")

NO ROUTE + HttpVerb ("Things/") => comes out as "api/odata/v{version}/PresentationLayerExampleAEntityOData03/" (ie...ignoring Verb)
NO ROUTE + HttpVerb ("api/odata/Things/") => comes out as "api/odata/v{version}/PresentationLayerExampleAEntityOData03/" (ie...ignoring Verb)
NO ROUTE + HttpVerb ("api/odata/v{version}/Things/" => comes out as "api/odata/v{version}/PresentationLayerExampleAEntityOData03/" (ie...ignoring Verb)
NO ROUTE + HttpVerb ("api/odata/v{version}/Things/Get" => comes out as "api/odata/v{version}/PresentationLayerExampleAEntityOData03/" (ie...ignoring Verb)
NO ROUTE + HttpVerb ("api/odata/Bang/G") => comes out as "api/odata/v{version}/PresentationLayerExampleAEntityOData03/" (ie...ignoring Verb)
 
NO ROUTE + Route ("api/odata/v{version}/Things/" + HttpGet => comes out as "api/odata/v{version}/PresentationLayerExampleAEntityOData03/" (ie...ignoring Verb)
```

To my eyes, the above combined urls were all mostly valid OData urls: `api/odata/v{version}/` + `Things/` + optionalactionhttpverb and should have passed.

#### Other Inputs?

`.UseEndpoints` is by default true when configuring OData. And I set it anyway.

#### Questions

- it will work without a `RouteAttribute`.
- but as the `RouteAttribute` appears to have to match the odata *Convention*...am I actually fooling myself that's its being looked at for value...?
- Certainly seems to throw it off if the Endpoint != Convention.
- What's going on!?!

#### Thank you

Really (it's been driving me nuts for a while).

Answer (score 2):

`ODataRoutePrefixAttribute` and `ODataRouteAttribute` are not specific to ASP.NET, it works in ASP.NET Core as well. They are still available in ASP.NET Core OData 8.0 Preview. But in [ASP.NET Core OData 8.0 RC](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/), these two attributes are gone.

For the use of `ODataRoutePrefixAttribute` and `ODataRouteAttribute`, you can refer to [Routing in ASP.NET Core OData 8.0 Preview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/routing-in-asp-net-core-8-0-preview/).

If these two properties don't work in your code, you can take a look at [Sam Xu's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65551331/using-odatarouteprefix-and-odataroute-for-odata-attributerouting-is-not-working/65620873#65620873) of this to see if your Url follows OData conventions.

For more examples and documentation, you can find at this [GitHub link](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData).

Comment: Hi Chen, thank you very for taking the time to recommend a way forward!
Seeing that the two prefixes are sunset approaches, went directly to using Route + Verb approach, as per  Sam Xu's explanation.
But not getting outcomes I would expect based on my understanding of his article.
In all cases, appears both Route and Verb are inconsistently being parsed. 
I've updated the question to add examples of the outcomes in case that helps you see something that I'm not. Thanks!

Comment: `ODataRoutePrefix/ODataRoute` should be valid OData Url, you can try to build `GetEdmModel()` like Sam Xu said, and try to use the route set in Edm to access.